# How to get indoor directions by using Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I have a problem using Google Direction API to get the route between two points(One point is outside the building and the other is inside the building).

When I use API to get the directions, only the routes outside building are returned as JSON data. But I want to show the indoor route for my application.

Is it possible to get the indoor directions using this Directions API or other API?